# Nikon D5300 mounting issues with 35mm

Tags: lens, nikon, dslr, troubleshooting

I just bought a (used) Nikon AF-S DX 35mm F1.8 G for my D5300 and I can't make it to work properly. My 18-55mm works fine and I've never had any issue attaching it to the camera, but when I got this new lens I tried to attach it normally and it won't make the "click" sound its supposed to do when attached correctly to the camera's body. With the 18-55, I place it on the lens mount with both white dots from the lens and camera side by side, twist the lens until the Nikkor logo is up and next to the top part of the camera and then it clicks, but with the 35mm nothing happens. Also, I feel like when trying to attach this lens it seems to be more rough and it has more friction when twisting it. I know the click sound is from that little metal pin in the lens mount from the camera but it doesnt seem to get it right with this news lens, although I know it should work perfectly according to the lens compatibility. When I turn on the camera with the lens in this state, the aperture value on the menu shows up as "F--" and the focus only works on manual so I guess the camera is not controlling the lens properly due to the electronic contacts not being fully connected.

I really don't know what's happening and why it seems that it doesn't get enough space to twist all the way around to get it right on the lens mount although it works perfectly with the common 18-55mm.

Comment: OK I GOT IT! Apparently, there was a very small screw on the lens metal ring that was preventing the lens to attach to the camera. I don't know why it was there but I'm pretty sure it isn't the right and original one because its kinda rounded and all the other screws where flat. Now the lens work perfectly.

Comment: If Steven Kersting's answer was useful to you or solved the problem, mark it as solved. :)

Comment: Hi, instead of posting the solution in a comment to your question, either mark the answer that helped you as the Accepted answer, or move your comment into its own answer and mark it accepted. It's entirely okay to ask and answer your own questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the mounting ring on the lens is bent, or it may have a screw coming loose/backing out; something is preventing the lens from rotating fully into place.

It is something that can be fixed, but I would return/exchange if possible.

Comment: There is indeed a screw in the lens that are loose but it won't come out, it seems that it isn't the right screw because its slightly smaller than the others in the back of the lens. I'll try to contact someone that can fix it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a comment.

My 35 mm lens has also significantly more friction than the kit lens. I do not know if you are not hearing the click because you are intimidated by the "abnormal" friction thinking it will get stuck.

The first thing is to carefully observe if there are no dents, rust, or chips of metal.
If you have a technician or service center near you, take it. Its probably nothing.

Comment: If the resistance is significantly greater than normal I would be concerned with premature lens mount wear/brassing. But just "firm" as compared to "loose" is not a concern.

Comment: I really don't hear any click sound and I know it doesn't attach correctly because the metal pin in the camera lens mount doesn't actually enters the hole its supposed to go in the lens. I'm already contacting a technician to fix this but here is a video just to show clearly whats hapenning: https://imgur.com/a/QV4FOzM

Comment: @Steven Kersting, No. The lens is new. And that happens with other new and Nikon original lenses.